# Ansible: have sudo but no root

Tags: redhat, ansible

I’d like to use Ansible to manage the configuration of a our Hadoop cluster (running Red Hat).

I have sudo access and can manually `ssh` into the nodes to execute commands. However, I’m experiencing problems when I try to run Ansible modules to perform the same tasks. *Although I have `sudo` access, I can’t become root*. When I try to execute Ansible scripts that require elevated privileges, I get an error like this:

> Sorry, user awoolford is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c echo
>   BECOME-SUCCESS- […] /usr/bin/python
>   /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446662360.01-231435525506280/copy' as awoolford on
>   [some_hadoop_node].

Looking through the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#become-allow-same-user), I thought that the `become_allow_same_user` property might resolve this, and so I added the following to `ansible.cfg`:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_allow_same_user=yes
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570202/getting-root-privileges-in-ansible) suggests that I need permissions to `sudo /bin/sh` (or some other shell). Unfortunately, that's not possible for security reasons. Here's a snippet from `/etc/sudoers`:

```
root            ALL=(ALL)   ALL
awoolford       ALL=(ALL)   ALL, !SU, !SHELLS, !RESTRICT
```

Can Ansible work in an environment like this? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you said you can manually ssh to the node and execute the commands, which user is that ?

Comment: I can `sudo [some_command]` as user `awoolford` providing that it isn't in one of the `!` lists (see snippet from `/etc/sudoers`).

Comment: Can you share an example play/role that throws the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you simply cannot execute `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` as your `/etc/sudoers` shows. What you could do is change ansible's default shell to something else (variable `executable` in `ansible.conf`).

Since your sudo policy allows everything by default (does not seem like really secure to me), and I suppose ansible expects an sh-compatible shell, as a really dirty hack you could copy `/bin/bash` to some other path/name and set the `executable` variable accordingly (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

In the playbook (some.yml) file, set

**runthisplaybook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: label_which_will_work_on_some_servers
  sudo: yes

  roles: 
    - some_role_i_want_to_run
```

Next, in the role//tasks/main.yml for the action which you have to run as sudo.. use something like **become_user** (where common_user is a variable defined in some role's defaults\main.yml file as common_user: "this_user_can_sudo":

```
- name: Run chkconfig on init script
  command: "sudo -u root /sbin/chkconfig --add tomcat" 

# Set execute permission on run_jmeter_test.sh
- name: Set execute permission on run_jmeter_test.sh
  command: "chmod -R 755 {{ jmeter_perf_tests_results }}"
  become_user: "{{ common_user }}"

# OR Set execute permission on run_jmeter_test.sh
- name: Set execute permission on run_jmeter_test.sh
  command: "sudo -u firstuser sudo -u seconduser chmod -R 755 {{ jmeter_perf_tests_results }}"
  become_user: "{{ common_user }}"

# OR Set execute permission on run_jmeter_test.sh
- name: Set execute permission on run_jmeter_test.sh
  command: "chmod -R 755 {{ jmeter_perf_tests_results }}"
  become_user: "{{ common_user }}"
```

**PS**: While running ansible-playbook,

ansible-playbook runthisplaybook.yml **--sudo-user=this_user_can_sudo -i hosts.yml -u user_which_will_connect_from_source_machine --private-key ${DEPLOYER_KEY_FILE}** --extra-vars "target_svr_type=${server_type} deploy_environment=${DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT} ansible_user=${ANSIBLE_USER}"

Answer (score 0):

After a research over the subject, as of Ansible **2.8** it doesn't seem you have a way to run commands as a different user using `become` without root permissions.

There's another way to achieve what you were asking without being so, how to put it, 'hacky'.

You can use the `shell` module with `sudo su - <user> -c "COMMAND"` to execute a command as a different user, without the need for **root access** to the original user.

For example,

```
  1 --- 
  2 - hosts: target_host
  3
  4   tasks:
  5   - shell: 'sudo su EXEC_USER -c "whoami"'
  6     register: x
  7
  8   - debug:
  9       msg: "{{ x.stdout_lines }}"   # This returns EXEC_USER
```

However, if your play is complex, you would need to break it down and wrap only the commands that are required to be executed as different user.

This isn't best practice (using sudo + shell instead of become), however that's a solution, and in my opinion a better one than creating dummy shell on every node you manage.

Answer (score -1):

I think now `sudo: yes` is depricated and replace with `become: yes`

```
---
- hosts: servers_on_which_you_want_to_run
  become: yes

  roles: 
    - some_role
```

The smiplist solution is just create a `ansible.cfg` in your playbook directory with the following content, if it doesn't accept `root` user:

```
[defaults]
sudo_user      = UsernameToWhichYouWantToUse
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.